# express js requiring url from another file

Tags: node.js, express, coffeescript

I have this:

./urls.coffee

```
urlConfig = [
    ["/", (req, res) -> res.send "hello world"]
]
module.exports = urlConfig
```

./utils/helpers.coffee

```
getUrl = (app, urlconfig)->
    for url in urlconfig
       app.get url[0], url[1]
module.exports.getUrl = getUrl
```

./app.coffee

```
express = require "express",
app = express();
helper = require "./utils/helper"
urls = require "./urls"

helper.getUrl app, urls
```

I'm trying to separate `url` from `app.coffee` by defining it in another file `url.coffee`.

But the callback cannot receive `(req, res)` args, the error is: 
`req is not defined`, but if the callback receives no args, it works fine. Anybody have any thoughts or suggestion?

Comment: Seems to work just fine (apart from `app.coffee` being a mix of JS and CoffeeScript and the require's have typos).

Comment: Don't know why, if i change the callback from anonymous function to pass a function's name, it works fine.

Comment: I'm testing with this as `urls.coffee`: https://gist.github.com/robertklep/5196631

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it be something like:

```
var express = require "express",
helper = require "./utils/helper"

app = express();
app.get = helper.getUrl
```

?

Comment: Not sure about that. If yes then i think i have to change the function. Can give me a hint?